# spl_autoload fault on remote server

Tags: php, spl-autoloader

Sorry for my bad language :)

On my local apache 2.2 php 5.3.13 all OK, but on remote server (php 5.3 too) spl_autoload throw logic exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Class
>   System\Core\Helper\Helper could not be loaded' in
>   /home/u737840143/public_html/index.php:6 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/u737840143/public_html/index.php(6):
>   spl_autoload('System\Core\Hel...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/u737840143/public_html/index.php on line 6

Code:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

\System\Core\Helper\Helper::getLanguage();

$router = new \System\Router\Router();
$router->init();
```

Remote folder structure corresponds to local.

Comment: Are you using a PHP based framework? Is this installed on both servers?

Comment: Debug: edit the script to load the class file using 'include class_file...' - does the file load and the class available? If so then your 'autoload' is wrong. If it doesn't load then change the 'include class_file...'  until it loads. Then sort out the 'spl_loader'.

Comment: No, I don't use any frameworks in this project, only PHP.

Comment: Ryan, I know that autoload is wrong, but I want to know - why?? It's a standart PHP function, it's works correctly in my local server, all my application based on this autoload function! what settings I need to change on the server, to make the application work correctly?

Comment: You are only using the 'default autoloader', **[spl-autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)**, which expects to find class files via the directories on the 'include path'. see **[set-include-path](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)** for adding to the path in your script. If you use namespaces the the 'symfony' components are worth a look. Internet search: 'php auto loader symfony components'

Comment: I have try to use `ini_set('include_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'); echo file_exists(get_include_path().'/System/Core/Helper/Helper.php');` and it returns "1"; but error of spl-autoloader have no changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer - `spl_autoloader()` can't work correctly with uppercases in many operating systems, but on Windows it works well.
So, after renaming all folders in lowercase (yes, and rewriting namespaces in ALL FILES...) everything started working.

```
<?php

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

spl_autoload_register();


try {

   \system\core\helper\Helper::getLanguage();

   $router = new \system\router\Router();
   $router->init();

} catch (\Exception $e){
   echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write the autoloader accordingly. You don't need to rename. Why do you think is Zend Framework (and others ofc) working on Linux and Windows without lowercase ? `\Zend_Action` for example.

Comment: I use windows. However, all Namespaces, Class names and 'includes' are 'exact' 'letter case perfect' names, so that they work on 'letter case operating systems' such as 'unix' or variants. I have my own 'auto class loader' it works on both operating systems and doesn't do anything special as regards 'letter case'. I use various other 'vendors' stuff such as 'symfony componets'.

Comment: Dan, I'll use default autoloader, if I want to write my own autoloader, I would do it :)  Ryan, I found this tip somwhere on the internet, and renaming folders make my application work correctly, so i think it is not so bad. And, as above, I try to use default classes - just for study.